# OData - Entity Framework Core - How to inject OData parameters into Linq query from Controller

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata, entity

I've been using `OData` for extensive filtering/sorting of objects (including relationships) with my Entity Framework Core powered asp.net API.

While the end result works fine, my current implementation does all additional filtering and so on `AFTER` the SQL connection.  This means I have to download all Results ahead of time.

Is there a way to inject `OData` pre my SQL database so that my filters will affect the actual query, thus reducing bandwidth significantly?  Additionally, I won't have to $Expand everything ahead of time.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you might be doing something fundamentally different to how OData was intended, I want to say wrong, but that's too strong ;) Can you provide a code or schema example of why you can't allow the $filter and $expand to pass through to the database?

Comment: @Chris Schaller The amount of relationships there are in some of my objects are many.  Sometimes I may only want to return the most basic object with out any filtering.  With the current oData usage, I must Include all EntityFramework relationships regardless of whether I query them.  So when I’m not trying to filter by say....user.posts...then I may not need all of that user.posts data.  I could make multiple controllers, I could add custom query args myself.  I just thought that oData might have their own solution for this.

Comment: Again can you offer a code example... _"I must Include all EntityFramework relationships regardless of whether I query them"_ means you are preventing OData from doing it's thing, At a high level, OData converts URL queries into SQL to reduce the memory processing and manipulation. An example will highlight the scenario, we can make suggestions on pure OData solutions or alternate methods.